# MEGA PHP API Array elements

Tags: php, api

I am working with the MEGA api in PHP by [smartinm](https://github.com/smartinm) which can be found [here](https://github.com/smartinm/mega-php-client).

I can access the data fine but when I return a query I am getting an array with the below values.

```
           [0] => Array
            (
                [h] => no idea
                [p] => no idea
                [u] => no idea
                [t] => 0
                [a] => Array
                    (
                        [n] => file_name.txt
                        [c] => this_only_appears_in_images
                    )

                [k] => no idea
                [s] => no idea
                [ts] => no idea
```

As you can see I have no idea what **h,p,u,t,a,k,s,ts** are. I know 'n' is name and 'c' appears only when an image file is there. Does anyone know off-hand what each element stands for?

Thanks, Niall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h: The ID of the node ;
p: The ID of the parent node (directory) ;
u: The owner of the node ;
t: The type of the node:
    0: File
    1: Directory
    2: Special node: Root (“Cloud Drive”)
    3: Special node: Inbox
    4: Special node: Trash Bin
a: The attributes of the node. Currently only contains its name.
k: The key of the node (used to encrypt its content and its attributes) ;
s: The size of the node ;
ts: The time of the last modification of the node.
```

Source: http://julien-marchand.fr/blog/using-the-mega-api-with-php-examples/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

> The result contains, for each node, the the following information:
>
> - **h**: The ID of the node
> - **p**: The ID of the parent node (directory) ;
> - **u**: The owner of the node
> - **t**: The type of the node:
>
>   - **0**: File
>   - **1**: Directory
>   - **2**: Special node: Root (“Cloud Drive”)
>   - **3**: Special node: Inbox
>   - **4**: Special node: Trash Bin
> - **a**: The attributes of the node. Currently only contains its name.
> - **k**: The key of the node (used to encrypt its content and its    attributes)
> - **s**: The size of the node
> - **ts**: The time of the last modification of the node.

#### [Source](http://julien-marchand.fr/blog/using-the-mega-api-with-php-examples/)

Comment: It won't allow me to 'Tick' both answers again but you were 100% correct also!